# RichText widget has vertical padding built into the text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a RichText widget that displays a time like "5:21" where the minutes are in bold and the seconds are not.

I am using the widget inspector tool to observe the bounds of the text.

The region of the RichText widget has a large amount of padding above and below the text (like 10 dp top and bottom). On the horizontal, there is no pad at all, the region is snug to the edges of the font. How can I get the region to be snug to the top and bottom of the font when using RichText?

```
return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        RichText(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          text: TextSpan(
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(
                text: "$minutes:",
                style: textStyle,
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: "$seconds".padLeft(2, '0'),
                style: textStyle.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "time",
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: please share your code snipet

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 10),
              child: RichText(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "$minutes:",
                      style: textStyle,
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "$seconds".padLeft(2, '0'),
                      style: textStyle.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "time",
            ),
```